# Grails: How to pass arrays to GSP pages

Tags: grails

I need to display list of directories in GSP pages. Can you please guide me how to pass this array to GSP.

Here is my below sample code.

```
         File dir = new File(petl_dir_path)
          def list= []                      
          dir.eachDir{ list << it.name }
```

Please  guide

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your 'list' is not an array, it's an instance of ArrayList. However, you can simply pass it to your view (in the following example, I assume you have the index action) like:

```
def index = {
  File dir = new File(petl_dir_path)
  def list= []                          
  dir.eachDir{ list << it.name }
  [dirs: list as String[]]
}
```

And then you can just process 'dirs' in your GSP.

Comment: Why cast/coerce the list into a String array?

Comment: Because the question asked about passing an array. I also wanted to show that his understanding of a List and an array is not fully correct.